# how to run a setup file(.exe) using pywinauto in windows?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, pywinauto

Actually i want some media codecs to be installed through my python code. I have used pyuac to run my script as an admin user in windows so that no authetication related interruption will be displayed.

```
import pywinauto, time, pyuac
import subprocess 

if not pyuac.isUserAdmin():
    pyuac.runAsAdmin()  

pig = subprocess.Popen(["C:\Users\VAIBH PC\Downloads\windows.8.codec.pack.v2.0.5.setup.exe"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE) 

time.sleep(1.0)
pwa_app = pywinauto.application.Application()

w_handle = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(title=u'Windows 8 Codec Pack           Setup', class_name='#32770')[0]
window = pwa_app.window_(handle=w_handle)
window.SetFocus()

ctrl = window['OK']
ctrl.Click()

time.sleep(5)

w_handle = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(title=u'Windows 8 Codec Pack   Setup', class_name='#32770')[0]
window = pwa_app.window_(handle=w_handle)
window.SetFocus()

ctrl = window['Button']
ctrl.Click()



ctrl = window['Button2']
ctrl.Click()



w_handle = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(title=u'Windows 8 Codec Pack  Setup', class_name='#32770')[0]
window = pwa_app.window_(handle=w_handle)
window.SetFocus()

ctrl = window['Button2']
ctrl.Click()
```

Comment: So what is the problem? Do you need a method name of the `Application` object which starts `*.setup.exe`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i got it:

```
import pywinauto
pwa_app = pywinauto.application.Application() 
pwa_app.start_(r'C:\Users\VAIBH PC\Downloads\windows.8.codec.pack.v2.0.5.setup.exe')
```